# How to perform prop type validation for children component?

Tags: reactjs

```js
const Parent = ({ username, children }) => {
let firstName = username.split(" ")[0];
let lastName = username.split(" ")[1];

// NOTE: Replace {children} with React.cloneElement(children,{firstName,lastName}) 
return (
<div>
<h1>`Welcome user {lastName}, {firstName}`</h1>
  {children}
  
</div>
);
}

const QuoteDisplay = ({firstName, lastName, randomQuote}) => {
       return(
       <h2>`{firstName}, {lastName} your quote for the day is: {randomQuote}`</h2>
       );
    }

QuoteDisplay.propTypes = {
    firstName:  React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    lastName:  React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    randomQuote:  React.PropTypes.string
    }

    
class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (<Parent username="funny Tom" > <QuoteDisplay randomQuote="Solve it" /></Parent>);
    }
 }
 
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

I have a parent component and different child components. I want to plug and play different children in parent. However there are some common parent props that might be required by children. This is how I am doing this now (above snippet). Please note parent is defined like below and I am not able to call React.clone in above editor so I have to highlight the difference below

Parent:

```
const Parent = ({ username, children }) => {
let firstName = username.split(" ")[0];
let lastName = username.split(" ")[1];
return (
<div>
<h1>`Welcome user {lastName}, {firstName}`</h1>
  {React.cloneElement(children, { firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName })}
</div>
);
}
```

This works fine, but it fails the prop type validation for quoteDisplay under the 'App' component as I am not passing the parameters at that stage. *However, as I am ultimately passing the username from the parent, it will receive and work fine.*

What are better approaches to handle this scenario? Should i be looking at something like redux or flux?

Added code snippet
(Disclaimer: this is a simplified example of my use case, which may have easier ways to do the same but please assume this is required for now)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would pass the props thought the parent and onto the children. So I would setup your App like this:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (<Parent username="funny Tom" randomQuote="Solve it"/>);
    }
 }
```

Then, Parent would take those props and pass the relevant props onto QuoteDisplay.

```
function Parent(props) {
 let firstName = props.username.split(" ")[0];
 let lastName = props.username.split(" ")[1];

 return (
  <div>
   <h1>`Welcome user {lastName}, {firstName}`</h1>
   <QuoteDisplay firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} randomQuote={props.randomQuote} />
 </div>
 );
}
```

And finally, QuoteDisplay takes in the props.

```
function QuoteDisplay(props) {
   return(
     <h2>`{props.firstName}, {props.lastName} your quote for the day is: {props.randomQuote}`</h2>
   );
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the parent will passdown the firstname and lastName eventually if you look carefully.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't call QuoteDisplay from inside Parent?

Comment: I understand the example is oversimplified but I have many child components but a common parent, with a common property that all children need to use. I dont want to pass through the common property to all children. QuoteDisplay is just an example of one such child. (I am trying to avoid using context)

Comment: Are you trying to avoid passing down props as well?

Comment: No, I am passing down props.

Comment: I am trying to avoid re-writing the logic like username split into first and last name everytime in an elegant way. Right now I just have QuoteDisplay, but let's say I have 3 other similar children say jokeDisplay,  bookDisplay, taskDisplay etc which need first Name and last Name props. I'd have to either create 4 different parent components for each or increase no of props in another higher component. Trying to reduce that.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Let me update my answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: This wasnt what i was looking for, but i used HOC to resolve it, FYI :)